# How to set request part for POST request with angular-file-upload and Spring?

Tags: angularjs, spring, angular-file-upload

Unfortunately [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42031959/how-to-correctly-attach-file-to-formdata-before-posting-to-server) does not help me. The problem appears to be that the request parameter `file` is not present in my POST request for some reason.

I am trying to upload a file, any file whether it's a binary file or a text file, in a POST request. The REST controller reveals:

```java
@PostMapping(WordEmbeddingApiPaths.UPLOAD_MODEL)
@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST, headers={"Content-Type=multipart/form-data"})
public ResponseEntity<WordVectorListDto> uploadModel(
        @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file, 
        RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) {

    LOGGER.debug("POST uploadModel");

    return new ResponseEntity<WordVectorListDto>((WordVectorListDto)null, HttpStatus.OK); 
}
```

and on the client I am running:

```
var uploader = $scope.uploader = new FileUploader({
    url: 'http://localhost:8080/rest-api/dl4j/we/uploadModel'
});

uploader.onAfterAddingFile = function($modelFile) {
    console.info('onAfterAddingFile', $modelFile);

    var fd = new FormData();

    fd.append('file', $modelFile.file);

    $http.post($modelFile.url, fd, {
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
        }, 
        params: {'file' : $modelFile.file}
    })
    .then(
        function (data) {
            alert("upload success");
        }, 
        function (data, status) {
            alert("upload error");
        }
     );

};
```

However, I am getting `400 Bad Request` as server response.

Any idea what the problem is?

---

**Update:**

I saw that an internal exception got thrown on the server side stating:

> `org.springframework.web.multipart.support.MissingServletRequestPartException`: Required request part 'file' is not present

I thought that I am setting this already - how can I make this right?

Comment: Please post the template and the code for the `FileUploader` service.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to correctly attach file to formData before POSTing to server?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42031959/how-to-correctly-attach-file-to-formdata-before-posting-to-server)

Answer (score 0):

### Posting FormData with AngularJS

When doing a POST with a [FormData API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) object, it is important to set the `Content-Type` header to `undefined`.

```
var fd = new FormData();

fd.append('file', $modelFile.file);

$http.post($modelFile.url, fd, {
    headers: {
        //'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
        'Content-Type': undefined
    }, 
    //params: {'file' : $modelFile.file}
})
```

When the [XHR send() method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/send) gets a FormData object created by the [FormData API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) it automatically sets the content type to `multipart/form-data` and includes the proper boundary.

By having the AngularJS framework override the content type, the boundary is not set properly.

---

### Debugging Small Programs

This question is an example of putting several things together without debugging each part.

This question has several unknown code components:

- An undebugged AngularJS POST method
- An undebugged Spring Backend
- An undebugged mysterious AngularJS service

This answer pointed out errors with the AngularJS POST method but there are a couple of other unknowns. Is the Spring backend working properly? Is the mysterious `FileUploader` service being used correctly?

Debugging involves isolating unknowns and testing them separately.

Does the Angular POST method work with a known backend such as [HTTP BIN - HTTP Request & Response Service](http://httpbin.org/)?

Does the Spring backend work with an uploader that has been tested?

For more information, see [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: Hi! I've set it to undefined but for some reason the parameter 'file' is still not present according the the exception thrown by Spring.

Comment: `FileUploader` service comes from the `angular-file-upload` package I installed with bower. The Spring backend is fine but it complains that the request parameter `file` is not present.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using **@EnableAutoConfiguration** then you need to do the following as discussed here https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/2958

1. **@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {MultipartAutoConfiguration.class})**
2. define the following beans

   @Bean(name = "multipartResolver")
   public CommonsMultipartResolver commonsMultipartResolver(){
       CommonsMultipartResolver resolver = new CommonsMultipartResolver();
       resolver.setMaxUploadSize(50*1024*1024);
       return resolver ;
   }

   @Bean
   @Order(0)
   public MultipartFilter multipartFilter(){
       MultipartFilter multipartFilter = new MultipartFilter();
       multipartFilter.setMultipartResolverBeanName("multipartResolver");
       return multipartFilter;
   }