# How to correctly attach file to formData before POSTing to server?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ajax, file-upload

I've been following this [FormData tutorial here](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/ridiculously-simple-ajax-uploads-with-formdata), however have yet to understand how the [formData object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) works.

#### My input form

[image]

```
<input type="file" id="file-id" class="w300px rounded4px" name="file" placeholder="PDF file">
<button class="btn-upload-pdf" ng-click="asub.uploadPDF()">Upload</button>
```

#### Here is the upload button function:

```
this.uploadPDF = () => {
    const formData = new FormData();
    const fileInput = document.getElementById('file-id');
    const file = fileInput.files[0];
    formData.append('pdf-file', file);
    console.log('formData', formData)

    return ApiFactory.insightPDF(formData).then((res) => {
        console.log('res', res);
        return res;
    });
};
```

When I log out the `fileInput` object `.files[0]` I see the file I just attached:

[image]

It would seem to mean that this object should be enough to send along to the POST. However this is the next step:

`formData.append('pdf-file', file);`

I log out `formData` before I send it into my Factory and this is the result, I don't see the key `pdf-file` or that PDF anywhere, just a bunch of methods? Where does the file get appended too? How does formData contain the actual PDF?

[image]

I need to attach something from the formData object I presume:

#### The Factory that makes the POST request

```
const insightPDF = (formData) => {
    console.log(' formData', formData)
    return $http.post('/app/api/insights_pdf', formData).then((res) => {
        console.log('PDF uploaded res', res)
        return res;
    }).catch(apiError);
};
```

Comment: You should be posting fromData not file.

Comment: Ah sorry, I am posting fromData, I just changed the var name to file when inside of the `insightPDF` function, I should probably change that back.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Set `Content-Type: undefined`

When posting objects created by the [FormData API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) it is important to set the content type header to `undefined`.

```
const insightPDF = (formData) => {
    console.log(' formData', formData)
    var config = { headers: {'Content-Type': undefined} };
    return $http.post('/app/api/insights_pdf', formData, config)
     .then((res) => {
        console.log('PDF uploaded res', res)
        return res;
    }).catch(apiError);
};
```

Normally the AngularJS framework, automatically add the content type header as `application/json` which overrides the content type set by the [XHR Send() method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/send). When the [XHR API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) sends a [FormData object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData), it automatically sets the content type to `multipart/form-data` with the proper boundary.

From the Docs:

> The $http service will automatically add certain HTTP headers to all requests
>
> To explicitly remove a header automatically added via `$httpProvider.defaults.headers` on a per request basis, Use the headers property, setting the desired header to `undefined`. For example:
>
> ```
> var req = {
>  method: 'POST',
>  url: 'http://example.com',
>  headers: {
>    'Content-Type': undefined
>  },
>  data: { test: 'test' }
> }
> ```
>
> [— AngularJS $http Service API Reference - Setting HTTP Headers](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#setting-http-headers)

[FormData objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) like [blobs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob) are host-defined objects non-native to JavaScript. Not all of their properties can be seen by `console.log` or `console.dir`. [Files](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File) are a special type of blob. The data is not necessarily loaded from disk. Usually, the data is streamed from disk only when needed by a specific API.

---

## Avoid Extra Overhead -- Send files directly

Content in `multipart/form-data` uses [base64 encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) which adds 33% extra overhead. If uploading only one file, it is more efficient to send the file blob directly.

```
//MORE Efficient; Avoids base64 encoding overhead

const insightPDF = (dataObject) => {
    var config = { headers: {'Content-Type': undefined} };
    return $http.post('/app/api/insights_pdf', dataObject, config)
     .then((res) => {
        console.log('PDF uploaded res', res)
        return res;
    }).catch(apiError);
};

var file = inputElem[0].files[0];
insightPDF(file);
```

If the server can accept binary content directly, it is best to send files that way. The [XHR API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) will automatically set the content type to that of the file.

Comment: Thanks! No more errors... now just need to finish the backend endpoint :) is there a way tho to see where the file is attached inside of the FormData object? When I log it out, it's still just a bunch of methods. What does the `formData.append('pdf-file', file);` do?

Comment: As I said in my answer, the `formData` object is host-environment object. It is an exotic non-native proxy for things in the host environment. JavaScript can only see the methods and properties made available to the language. Under the hood there is more. Web APIs like `FileReader` and  `XHR send` have connections under the hood to host environment methods and properties.

Comment: To see what is attached inside the FormData object, use the [formData.entries()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/entries) method. For an example, see [form data is not appending file object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55300330/form-data-is-not-appending-file-object/55306625#55306625).