# Upload binary file and save it like an Excel in server

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, excel, file-upload

I have a JavaScript function which reads an excel file and return me an object ArrayBuffer in `document.getElementById("content").value`:

```
  <script type = "text/javascript">
        function readFile(files){
            console.log("DEntro de readFile");
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.readAsArrayBuffer(files[0]);
            reader.onload = function(event){
                var arrayBuffer = event.target.result;
                array = new Uint8Array(arrayBuffer);
                binaryString = String.fromCharCode.apply(null, array);
                document.getElementById("fileContent").value = event.target.result;     
            }
        }
  </script>
```

So, I would like to know, how can I send this object ArrayBuffer to the server and in the server save this ArrayBuffer in an excel file generating the original Excel.

What can I do?

**EDIT I:**
I think I'm doing something wrong, because I create the file, but with strange characters and with only 31 bytes.

**JavaScript:**

```
    function readFile(files){
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.readAsArrayBuffer(files[0]);
        reader.onload = function(event){
            document.getElementById("fileContent").value = event.target.result;     
        }

    }
```

**Angular JS**
With this function I send data to the server in a JSON:

```
 self.uploadFile = function(){
     var data = {
        file    :   document.getElementById("fileContent").value,
     };
     publicDataServices.sendData("http://gnsys.local/publico/test/up", data).then(function(response){
         switch(parseInt(response.result)){
             case 0:
                 console.log("OK!!!");
                 break;
             case 3:    //Error de Sistemas
                 console.log("testControllers.js::uploadFile: Error de sistemas");
                 break;                              
         }
     });
 }
```

**PHP:**

```
    $params = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'),true);
    $property = new PropertyReader();
    $fileRoute = $property->getProperty("scripts.ruta.querys");
    $fileName = $fileRoute . "prueba.xls";

    $input = fopen('php://input', 'rb');
    $file = fopen($fileName, 'wb');

    stream_copy_to_stream($input, $file);
    fclose($input);
    fclose($file);
```

**Edit II (it works!):**

**Angular JS:**

```
 self.uploadFile = function(){
     publicDataServices.sendData("http://gnsys.local/publico/test/up", document.getElementById("file").files[0]).then(function(response){
         switch(parseInt(response.result)){
             case 0:
                 console.log("OK!!!");
                 break;
             case 3:    //Error de Sistemas
                 console.log("testControllers.js::uploadFile: Error de sistemas");
                 break;                              
         }
     });
 }
```

**PHP:**

```
    $property = new PropertyReader();
    $fileRoute = $property->getProperty("scripts.ruta.querys");
    $fileName = $fileRoute . "prueba.xls";

    $input = fopen('php://input', 'rb');
    $file = fopen($fileName, 'wb');

file_get_contents and file_put_contents
        stream_copy_to_stream($input, $file);
        fclose($input);
        fclose($file);
```

I just only to know how to get the original file name.

**Edit III (sending file name):**
**Angular js:**

```
 self.uploadFile = function(){ 
        var promise = $q.defer();
        var headers = {
            "file-name" :   document.getElementById("file").files[0].name
        }
        $http.post("http://gnsys.local/publico/test/up", document.getElementById("file").files[0], {headers:headers})
        .success(function(response, status, headers, config){
            promise.resolve(response);
            console.log("resultado: " + response.result);
        })
        .error(function(data){
            //Error de sistemas
            console.log("Error en sendData: " + data)
        })

        return promise.promise;      
 }
```

**PHP:**

```
    $property = new PropertyReader();
    $fileRoute = $property->getProperty("scripts.ruta.querys");
    $fileName = $fileRoute . "prueba.xls";
    //With this foreach we get all the headers so I can detect which i the right header to get the file name
    foreach (getallheaders() as $name => $value) {
        $log->writeLog(get_class($this) . "::" . __FUNCTION__ . ": name: " . $name . " value: " . $value);
    }

    $input = fopen('php://input', 'rb');
    $file = fopen($fileName, 'wb');

    stream_copy_to_stream($input, $file);
    fclose($input);
    fclose($file);
```

It works perfectly!

Comment: What is purpose of `String.fromCharCode()` call if requirement is to send `ArrayBuffer` to server? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37491759/trying-to-pass-todataurl-with-over-524288-bytes-using-input-type-text/37491895#37491895

Comment: Maybe is not necessary String.fromCharCode(). I'l try to delete that code. Thanks!!!

Comment: Send `.files[0]` property of `<input type="file">` element to server. `.value` is a string, `C:\\fakepath`. Why do you call `json_decode` at `php`? `publicDataServices.sendData("http://gnsys.local/publico/test/up", document.getElementById("fileContent").files[0])`, at `php` remove first line.

Comment: `FileReader` is not necessary. `input.onchange = function() {
 publicDataServices.sendData("http://gnsys.local/publico/test/up", document.getElementById("fileContent").files[0])
}`. Though have not tried `angugularjs`, not sure how the library handles sending `Blob` to server. You could alternatively use `XMLHttpRequest()` or `fetch()` to send `File` object to server. `request.send(document.getElementById("fileContent").files[0])`, or  `fetch("path/to/server", {method:"POST", body:document.getElementById("fileContent").files[0]})`

Comment: It works!!! It works!!! I think I'm gonna cry!!! Thank you so much!!! But I've got another question. I need to send the name or get in the server the name of the file. How can I do that?

Comment: You could set the file name at a user defined header, then parse the header at `php`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/541430/how-do-i-read-any-request-header-in-php, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2902621/fetching-custom-authorization-header-from-incoming-php-request

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to correctly attach file to formData before POSTing to server?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42031959/how-to-correctly-attach-file-to-formdata-before-posting-to-server)

Answer (score 1):

It is not necessary to convert `File` object to `ArrayBuffer`. You can `POST` `File` object to server and utilize `fopen()`, `"php://input"`, `file_get_contents()` at `php`, see [Trying to Pass ToDataURL with over 524288 bytes Using Input Type Text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37491759/trying-to-pass-todataurl-with-over-524288-bytes-using-input-type-text/)

Comment: I need to read an excel file and send to the server, but I can't use POST, I have to send an stream.

Comment: _"but I can't use POST, I have to send an stream"_ What do you mean by "send an stream"? How is file sent to server?

Answer (score 0):

When sending a file blob using the AngularJS $http service, it is important to set the content type header to the primitive value `undefined`.

```
var config = { headers: { 'Content-Type': undefined } };

$http.post(url, file[0], config).then(function(response) {
    var data = response.data;
    var status = response.status;
    console.log("status: ", status);
});
```

Normally the $http service sets the content type header to `application/json`. By setting the content type header to `undefined`, the [XHR Send Method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/send) will set the header to the appropriate value.