# form data is not appending file object

Tags: angularjs, form-data

I have a problem in appending file object with form data,after appending file object to form data,form data is empty object.Please suggest

```js
scope.uploadDigitalSignature = function (form) {
if (scope.digitalFiles.length) {
scope.docDetails.aliasName = scope.docDetails.aliasName;
scope.docDetails.digipassword = scope.docDetails.digipassword;
scope.docDetails.certificate = scope.docDetails.certificate;

var file = scope.digitalFiles[0];
var formData = new FormData(this);
formData.append('file', file);
// FileUpload.upload(scope.digitalFiles,docId,function(success,blobData){
var config = {
headers: { 
'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
}
}; 
var blobData = {
"file" : scope.docDetails.certificate
};
AdminService.uploadDigitalSignature(function(){
toastr.success('Signature uploaded successfully');
},docId,scope.docDetails.aliasName,scope.docDetails.digipassword ,blobData,config);
//}

//);
}
};
```

[image: console log of file object and form data]

Comment: When using the [FormData API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) to POST files, it is important to set the [Content-Type header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type) to `undefined`.

Comment: [It is more efficient to send a file directly.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45599921/5535245)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A [FormData Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) is an exotic object whose contents is not directly available to JavaScript.

To retrieve the contents of a FormData object, use its `.entries()` method:

```
var contents = Array.from(formData.entries());
console.log(contents);
```

For more information, see [MDN Web API Reference - FormData.entries()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/entries)